# instance variables in objective c .m file

Tags: ios, objective-c

In Objective c, what is the differences between **instance variables** `var1` and `var2` showing below?

(This code is in one .m file, does it make any difference if the @interface is in a header file & @implementation is in implementation file? I mean any difference comparing with that in one file regarding to the two instance variables.)

```
@interface MyService {
 NSString *var1;
}

@end

@implementation MyService {
 NSString *var2;
}
@end
```

Comment: What  solution do you expect Leem.fin?

Comment: Do you understand my answer?

Answer (score 4):

The difference between them is visibility.  The variable defined in the `@interface` section is visible to any code which imports the interface.  The variable declared in the `@implementation` section is only visible to code within the class implementation.

If the `@interface` is declared in the implementation file, it will act, for all practical purposes, the same as declaring it in the `@implementation` section.

Comment: I don't understand your second paragraph, it sounds like "if @interface is declared in the implementation file, it is the same as it is declared in implementation file" what? Could you please use some code snippet to explain more clearly? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Instance variables declared in the implementation are implicitly
>   hidden (effectively private) and the visibility cannot be changed -
>   @public, @protected and @private do not produce compiler errors (with
>   the current Clang at least) but are ignored.

you can found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840884/private-ivar-in-interface-or-implementation)

Comment: What about my question about define in one implementation file (both `@interface` & `@implementation` like my code shows VS separate files, header file & implementation files), does it make any difference regarding to var1 and var 2

Comment: Like Avi told you just in visibility that this variable will be `@public or @protected or @private`, just it :).

Answer (score 0):

I have deep searched for your question.Well asked Leem.fin brother.I tried sample one

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
@interface SecondViewController ()
{
    NSString *variableOne;
}
@end

@implementation SecondViewController
{
   NSString *variableTwo;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  [self setValueToString];
   NSLog(@"The variable One is - %@",variableOne);
   NSLog(@"The variable Two is - %@",variableTwo);
}

-(void)setValueToString
{
    variableOne = @"iOS";
    variableTwo = @"iPhone";
}
```

The printed results are

```
 The variable One is - iOS
 The variable Two is - iPhone
```

But when I tried to access these in Class method

```
+(void)changeStrings
{
   variableOne = @"iPad"; //I get error here
   variableTwo = @"iMac"; //I get error here
}
```

The error shows

> Instance variable 'variableOne' accessed in class method
>
> Instance variable 'variableTwo' accessed in class method

From above code I understood

> Both are instance variables
>
> That can be accessed only in instance methods
>
> There is no difference between them

[So Where to put](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566862/where-to-put-ivars-in-modern-objective-c)

[Difference between them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560301/difference-between-declaring-an-ivar-in-interface-and-putting-variable-in-impl)

[Difference between putting variable inside interface and implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31895332/difference-between-declaring-a-variable-under-implementation-and-interface-und)